# ssl svn user login problem

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, openssl

I've a subversion server, on Apache (on WindowsXP), which is accessible over the net using http. I wanted to use ssl/https to access it. I haven't messed around with forcing http -> https yet, and can login using http:// fine. However, if I use https://, the login fails, and I get an "Authentication required!" 401 error message.

I guess it's a configuration issue on my server(?), but haven't found a solution yet.

Any ideas?

edit 
I can connect and login via https://localhost ok, but not over the net via the ip address. I did put the ip address in when creating the certificate (via makecert).

snippet of conf file (I can add more if necessary):

httpd-ssl:

```
`VirtualHost _default_:443>
        #   General setup for the virtual host    t
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
        ServerName localhost:443
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
        <IfModule log_config_module>
            CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
        </IfModule>

        SSLEngine on

        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        #SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server-dsa.crt"
        SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"`
```

httpd.conf excerpt:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl.scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
</IfModule>

<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNParentPath C:\SVN
  #SVNIndexXSLT "/svnindex.xsl"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion repositories"
  AuthUserFile passwd
  #AuthzSVNAccessFile svnaccessfile
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Comment: Can you provide the apache virtual host configs for the http, and https sites?

Comment: Update: it's all working fine now, but I can't pinpoint exactly what caused it to work (which is a bit annoying, but anyway...).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this under ServerName:

```
ServerAlias 127.0.0.1:443
```

Comment: I just tried that (in the httpd-ssl.conf), but it hasn't worked. It's still getting past the warning message with the certificate not being trusted, but when I get to the subversion login, it fails that. It's still working fine on my local machine.

Comment: So everything is working the way you want it to when you go to "localhost", but not when you go to "127.0.0.1"?

Comment: no, sorry, it's when I go to my actual ip address from an external pc. That still works fine via "http :// 82.xxx.xxx.xxx", but not "https :// 82.xxx.xxx.xxx". If I try the https://localhost etc. on the actual server machine, that works fine, after the cert. warning. (can't work out how to tag https, hence the spaces!)